# How do I find out the Button ID from a Website for Python?

Tags: python, youtube

I'm trying to use Python to create a file that allows me to start a YouTube stream with one click. I use pythons webbrowser for this. But to press the button I need to know the ID of the start button. Unfortunately, I'm not really smart about the inspector from my browser.
I hope you can help me with this problem.
Jonas

```
import webbrowser
url = "https://studio.youtube.com/channel/........./livestreaming/stream"
chrome_url = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"
browser = webbrowser.get(chrome_url)
browser.open(url)
button = browser.find_element_by_id(button_id)
button.click()
```

[Youtube Inspector Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhlvx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you can try using Selenium for the same purpose, code for the same is :

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from time import sleep
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,executable_path="C://downloads//chromedriver.exe")

    driver.get("url for the youtube video")
    sleep(2)
    element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='ytp-large-play-button ytp-button']")
    element.click()
```